# VBA variable has HTML code in it. How do I render this? OR how do I open a win.http.response text

Tags: php, vba, post, outlook

I have a VBA script running in outlook.
It gets data from emails and stores certain elements in a variable.
This variable is then posted to a website which uses php to take the varbale and displyas the data in a table for a user to check and deal with.
It currently works wiht a get request.
I need to upgrade this to a post as I am hitting the max lenth of a get.

The post script below sends the variable to the server and if I do a MsgBox with http.ResponseText is shows the HTML of the website with the post request data rendered on the site.

```
    Dim http As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    Dim UrlToPostTo As String, UrlRedirectedTo As String
    UrlToPostTo = "http://removedManually/phpPostDir/index.php"
    Set http = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    http.Open "POST", UrlToPostTo, False
    http.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    Dim data As String
    data = "name1=value1&name2=value2&name3=value3"
    http.Send (data)
    MsgBox http.ResponseText
```

PHP on the webpage:

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

The http.ResponseText result which is shown in the msgbox in VBA:

```
Array
(
    [name1] => value1
    [name2] => value2
    [name3] => value3
)
```

What I need to do is now open this ResponseText in a browser for the user to view and interact with.

The data shown here is a example for simplicity.

If anyone can think of a better idea of how to pass data from a VBA, to a website for the user to use then I would happily look into it. This is the best method I could come up with.

Comment: Where is your PHP? What have you tried? What's the expected output? What are you currently getting? The question is pretty unclear at this point.

Comment: Sorry, the php is simply a print_r($_POST). The responseText has the data posted inside it but this is returned to VBA. I need to know how to then render this HTML or view the webpage on a browser as the HTML code is currently saved in a VBA variable.

Comment: If you just dump what you get, of course it will just return the same. Anyway, you keep saying "render this HTML". What HTML? There's no HTML in the request. You really need to update your question and give us an example of the expected output. Your question makes no sense in it's current state.

Comment: You have PHP returning HTML to VBA to render in a browser?  Why?  and How?  Can you give some more background?  This sounds like there's something awfully convoluted going on a couple steps back in the process.  Please [edit] your question to add more information about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - i'm betting on an "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)"...

Comment: Ok, I have put a large edit and update. I hope this is now clearer.

Comment: _"in a browser for the user to view and interact with"_ - I'm confused. Do you simply want to send the user to a web page (with the post data) or do you want to do a post request and return some response (since you're mentioning _"f I do a MsgBox with http.ResponseText "_)? Please look at your question from our perspective. We are dependent on _you_ to tell us _everything_ about your issue and what you're trying to do. Since this question still is super unclear, even though I've asked for clarification several times, I'm out...

Comment: I don't mind. All I need to do is have the user view the website with the posted data on it. If I can send the user to the site with the posted data fine, I know the post is working as I can see this in the ResponseText, that is to test it. And you say _I'm out..._ sorry, I didn't realise this was Dragons Den!

Comment: Yeah, I don't really get it either; so you get the content of one web page and you want the user to.... do what? View that content in another web page? Elaborate a bit and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it using:

```
    objIE.document.Write response
    Set xmlhttp = Nothing
```

---

Full code is anyone needs it:

```
    Dim objIE As Object, xmlhttp As Object
    Dim response As String

    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    objIE.navigate "about:blank"
    objIE.Visible = True

    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    xmlhttp.Open "POST", "http://158.234.65.113/JSONForm/index.php", False
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    xmlhttp.Send finalJSON

    response = xmlhttp.ResponseText
    objIE.document.Write response
    Set xmlhttp = Nothing
```